# Get row index of edited cell in DataTable.ColumnChangedEvent

Tags: c#, vb.net, datatable

How do i get the row id of the cell that was edited using ColumnChangedEvent of Data Table

i tried as follow :

```
Private Sub OnColumnChanged(sender As Object, e As DataColumnChangeEventArgs)

    {

    int RowIndex= e.Row.Table.Rows.IndexOf(e.Row);
    }
```

The RowIndex is returned as -1 may be because this row has not been updated in the data table ,is it so???
anyother way of finding the row index of the cell ?

Comment: is it now just e.Row or am I missing something ?

Comment: e.Row gives me the current row as per MSDN but why am i not able to get this row in the row collection of data table .

Comment: Is this a new row that has not been accepted and put in the collection ?

Comment: exactly micah,,,, i got the problem. the row that raised the column changed event was a new row that was inserted using NewRow() and not yet added to Row collection.So IndexOf was returning -1.

Answer (score 0):

This is a new row, it has not been committed and is not in the row collection and therefore returns a -1

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what the OP had worked for me under the DataTable.RowChanged()

e.g.

```
public static void DataTable_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{
    int iRowIndex;

    if (e.Action == DataRowAction.Change)
        iRowIndex = e.Row.Table.Rows.IndexOf(e.Row);
}
```